# Cannot remove certain lines without my coloring going to white

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I’m trying to make a logo with a T. I’ve drawn a couple of lines through the upper part of the T to be able to color it in different colors. When I then try to remove the lines which are going through the T, it removes major parts of the letter, not just the lines I want to remove. [image]

Comment: Hi. It's bit unclear what you want to achieve. Please provide a bit more explanation.

Comment: It would appear that your T is not a single shape, but rather a collection of random shapes.

Comment: Lube abd cikirsig is same object

Comment: Maybe remove the stroke rather than the line?  Can't really figure out what you are asking or trying to do here. Can you add more details?  Is that image what you are trying to achieve, or your failed attempt? What should it look like?  Also please don't take photos of your screen with your phone. Take a proper screenshot.

Comment: I’m trying to color the letter in different colors. To do that, I’ve drawn lines through the T to use the shape builder tool to color the different parts of the letter, however, when I remove the lines that I inserted to divide the letter to color it, parts of the letter just disappear.

Comment: @Tobbe - Then don't remove the lines. Remove the strokes instead.

Comment: Or you can simply remove the color from that line.